# How to capture POST content parameters in Jenkins declarative syntax?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

**How do you capture POST content parameters in code in Jenkins declarative syntax pipeline script?**

This is an example of how to do it with scripted syntax:

```
node {
 properties([
  pipelineTriggers([
   [$class: 'GenericTrigger',
    genericVariables: [
     [ key: 'committer_name', value: '$.actor.name' ],
     [ key: 'committer_email', value: '$.actor.emailAddress' ],
     [ key: 'ref', value: '$.changes[0].refId'],
     [ key: 'tag', value: '$.changes[0].ref.id', regexpFilter: 'refs/tags/'],
     [ key: 'commit', value: '$.changes[0].toHash' ],
     [ key: 'repo_slug', value: '$.repository.slug' ],
     [ key: 'project_key', value: '$.repository.project.key' ],
     [ key: 'clone_url', value: '$.repository.links.clone[0].href' ]
    ],

    causeString: '$committer_name pushed tag $tag to $clone_url referencing $commit',
    token: 'my_token',
    printContributedVariables: true,
    printPostContent: true,
    regexpFilterText: '$ref',
    regexpFilterExpression: '^refs/tags/.*'
   ]
  ])
 ])

 stage("Test") {
  deleteDir()
  def msg = "hello, world!"
  emailext (subject: "Hello", \
                      mimeType: "text/html",\
                      body: "${msg} <br> \
                      committer_name ${committer_name} <br> \
                      committer_email ${committer_email} <br> \
                      ref ${ref} <br> \
                      tag ${tag} <br> \
                      commit ${commit} <br> \
                      repo_slug ${repo_slug} <br> \
                      project_key ${project_key} <br> \
                      clone_url ${clone_url} <br> \
                      ",
                      from: "Jenkins@company.com", \
                      to: "${committer_email}")
```

[This article](https://plugins.jenkins.io/generic-webhook-trigger/) claims that equivalent scripted syntax would be:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  triggers {
    GenericTrigger {
      genericVariables {
        genericVariable {
          key( "committer_name" )
          value( "\$.actor.name" )
          expressionType( "JSONPath" )
        }
      }

      token( "my_token" )
      printContributedVariables(true)
      printPostContent(true)
      regexpFilterText( "\$ref" )
      regexpFilterExpression( "^refs/tags/.*" )
    }
  }

  stages {
    stage( "Test" ) {
      steps {
        deleteDir()
      }
    }
  }
```

(I stripped down the Test stage to reduced sources of error -- it should be inconsequential to this question).

...whereas in reality, it produces this error:

```
WorkflowScript: 4: Triggers definitions cannot have blocks @ line 4, column 5.
       GenericTrigger {
       ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:142)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:561)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:522)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:337)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)
Finished: FAILURE
```

**What is correct declarative syntax "equivalent" to the working scripted syntax** -- i.e. how can I capture POST content parameters with declarative syntax?

I'd specifically like to learn how to do this "in code", i.e. not using the `Varianble`/`Expression` fields of `Post content parameters` in the Jenkins GUI.

Answer (score 0):

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  triggers {
    GenericTrigger (
      genericVariables: [
        [ key: "committer_name", value: "\$.actor.name" ],
        [ key: "committer_email", value: "\$.actor.emailAddress" ],
        [ key: "ref", value: "\$.changes[0].refId" ],
        [ key: "tag", value: "\$.changes[0].ref.id" ],
        [ key: "commit", value: "\$.changes[0].toHash" ],
        [ key: "repo_slug", value: "\$.repository.slug" ],
        [ key: "project_key", value: "\$.repository.project.key" ],
        [ key: "clone_url", value: "\$.repository.links.clone[0].href" ],
      ],

      causeString: '$committer_name pushed tag $tag to $clone_url referencing $commit',
      token: "my_token",
      printContributedVariables: true,
      printPostContent: true,
      regexpFilterText: "\$ref",
      regexpFilterExpression: "^refs/tags/.*"
    )
  }

  stages {
    stage( "Build" ) {
      steps {
        deleteDir()
      }
    }
  }

  post {
    always {
      emailext( subject: "Hello",
                from: "jenkins@company.com",
                to: "\${committer_email}",
                mimeType: "text/html",
                body: "hello world <br> \
                       committer_name ${committer_name} <br> \
                       committer_email ${committer_email} <br> \
                       ref ${ref} <br> \
                       tag ${tag} <br> \
                       commit ${commit} <br> \
                       repo_slug ${repo_slug} <br> \
                       project_key ${project_key} <br> \
                       clone_url ${clone_url} <br> \
                       " )
    }
  }
}
```